# A wrong wallet situation

Tags: transactions, blockchain, wallet, address, private-key

On 9th of this month I have my dad send me some bitcoin and I gave him my wallet for the payment.. after a while he told me he sent it I didn’t see it and I taught it was network and I would get it anytime soon it’s been 3 days before I realized he sent the bitcoin to my address buh a wrong letter match or something I really don’t understand the situation my wallet was written at the stop of the transaction and underneath where it says to: it was a different ending from my own just 1 later mixed up .. the question is can I get hold on the coin ? At any chance ?[image]

So please guys anyone tell me what my chances are. Thank you

Comment: The address bc1qt9exjzedr9tzrlx3h6ckcjhtu2lk8w6ypny9jk appears to be a valid address which is basically impossible on a single letter mixup. Did you check whether it might actually be the correct address, but your wallet is just not properly synchronized with the network?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin addresses have a checksum, so that mistyping a single letter should be detected as a mistake and money not sent.

If money was sent to an address neither you nor anyone else controls, the money is gone forever.

You can check exactly what transactions have occurred for a Bitcoin address at any of many [blockchain explorers](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer) -- for example [Blockchair](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/address/bc1qt9exjzedr9tzrlx3h6ckcjhtu2lk8w) shows no transactions relating to the address in the screenshot

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about that 